# How to serialize transient fields in the model via FlexJson?

Tags: json, serialization, playframework, flexjson

I am using Play Framework to expose REST API, which returns some JSON objects.
To simplify the API usage, I would like to return a "calculated" field in the response.

Unfortunately, in my tests, while **FlexJson** does not ignore the **transient** model fields completely, but always sets them to 'null'.

More details:

In the **model** class, I define:

```
@Transient
public String currencyName;
```

The **only constructor** of the class set the value to "dollar" (for debugging purposes):

```
this.currencyName = "dollar";
```

When serializing the class using FlexJson, when the 'currencyName' field is not specified in the include/ exclude - the result always looks like:

```
"currencyName":null
```

Any idea what got wrong, and how to get the field value serialized into JSON?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition if your field is transient it will not be serialized. Perhaps this field should not be transient in your application if the state matters.

Comment: Thanks. I am using serialization in order to generate "clean" JSON, not transfer object "state" between apps. My thought was that instead of configuring which fields from "this.currency" to "print out" into JSON, use calculated fields to specify the JSON format directly. Any thought?

Comment: If you are not interested in persisting this field or holding the state why don't you remove this field altogether. You can have a method wich calculates and return this value i.e. String getCurrencyName()

Comment: Alternatively use the exclude method from the serializer: new JSONSerializer().exclude("currencyName").serialize("Currency", currency);

Comment: Thanks a lot, "emt14". I implemented  String getCurrencyName() - worked exactly as you described.